# Java S3TransferManager reads entire file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm writing an application that downloads a big file from an external website I have no control over, and then uploads a copy of it to an S3 bucket (among other things) using version 2 of the AWS Java SDK.  The S3TransferManager is injected by Spring Batch.

```
URL website = new URL("https://big_website_url");

HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)website.openConnection();

try(ReadableByteInputChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(huc.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("filename.zip"))) {
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, huc.getContentLengthLong());
}

huc.disconnect();


String uploadFileKey = "my/download/path/filename.zip";

UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = 
   UploadFileRequest.builder()
       .putObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket("mybucket").key(uploadFileKey))
       .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
       .source(Paths.get("filename.zip"))
       .build();

FileUpload fileUpload = s3TransferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);
```

The file can be in excess of 900 MB.  I'm also using Spring Boot's Docker image plugin to produce the app which runs in Kubernetes:

```
mvn spring-boot:boot-image
```

The image produced by Spring Boot has a maximum direct memory buffer size of 10 MB.  I'm aware that I can change it, but I'm trying to keep the container's memory footprint as low as possible.

The problem is that the S3TransferManager reads the entire file into memory before uploading it.  From the [SDK documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/model/UploadFileRequest.Builder.html#source(java.nio.file.Path)):

"File will be read entirely and may be read multiple times in the event of a retry."

With a 900 mb file and a 500 mb memory limit, is there any way to get the S3TransferManager to read bits of the file at a time instead of all into memory, or do I have to fall back to doing multipart upload requests at low level?

Comment: Dont use that method, use the multipart instead, since you can upload in packets of x amount of mb, instead of the entire file. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html

Comment: There's no mention of the data being read fully into **memory**, and in case of retries there would be no need for a re-read if it were in memory. You seem to be misinterpreting the javadoc.

Comment: Although there's no mention of the data being read fully into memory, I still run out of heap space when transferring the file, even with a 64 MB max directory memory size and a 500 mb memory limit.